# How does ruby parse 2 /3/ 4 as 2 ÷ 3 ÷ 4?

Tags: ruby, parsing

A lot of ruby's syntax and parsing is relatively logical, but I am confused as to how ruby knows, from context, that `2 /3/ 4` is 2 ÷ 3 ÷ 4 instead of parsing `/3/` as a regex? It's a correct parsing, but `/3/` is also a valid regex, and how would it know that `/3/` is not a regex.

I thought that this might be a numeric literal thing, but if you do

```
a = 6
b = 4
c = 2

a /b/ c
```

Ruby still parses this as division. How does this work?

Actually, I realized there is more to this question,

let's say I have this

```
def a(x)
  x
end

a = 4
b = 2
i = 4

a /b/i #=> 0
```

How is `a /b/i` parsed as `0` instead of `/b/i`
as in why does `a /b/i` get parsed as `a./(b./(i))` instead of `a(/b/i)`?

Comment: _how would it know that /3/ is not a regex_ -- Because the word "match" nor the symbol "~" appears anywhere in the line?

Comment: @7stud `/3/` on its own with nothing else is a valid Regex.

Comment: Okay.  Parsing rule 1) if nothing outside of //, then regex.  2) If characters outside of //, and none of them spell "match" and none are "~", then division.

Comment: @7stud That's not true once again. `/a/i` is a valid regex. The key was no prefixes apparently.

Comment: Yet, if there's a space between the two, it is an error. Parsing rule 1) if nothing outside of //, then regex. 2) If characters immediately after trailing /, then check against valid modifiers, if valid modifier, then regex, otherwise division.  3) Other characters outside of //, and none of them spell "match" and none are "~", then division.  In any case, you can build up a parsing rule that takes care of all the possibilities, and if it can't then the syntax has to be invalid.

Comment: Note that `a`, `a /b/` and `a /b/ c` are three completely different situations. The second is passing a regular expression to a function `a` if one's defined. The third only makes sense if they're all variables. You'll get parse errors otherwise.

Comment: @tadman Now I have a question. Let's say I have `def a(b); b; end` and then I have `a, b, i = 1, 2, 3`. How is `a /b/i` `0` instead of `/b/i`?

Comment: @EliSadoff, It's a complicated parsing rule that has to be built up from humble beginnings.  You really can't think of any logic that could account for  what you are seeing, e.g. if i is a lcoal variable then division, not regex?

Comment: @7stud That's pretty much what my question was trying to ask. How the hell does this work?

Comment: The answer: a complicated parsing rule.

Comment: @7stud certainly, I just would like to know what the actual rule is.

Comment: http://programmingisterrible.com/post/42432568185/how-to-parse-ruby

Comment: Should be defined somewhere in these 11.5k lines: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y

Comment: BTW, when you write `a/b/c` on a piece of paper (`a` above `b` above `c` with division lines of different width inbetween), it's easy to see the difference between `a/(b/c)` and `(a/b)/c`. When you type it in one line, it becomes ambigous, and shouldn't be used. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/correct-precedence-of-division-operators

Comment: Ripper is a great lib (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) : `require 'ripper'; require 'pp'; pp Ripper.sexp('6/3/2')`

Comment: @7stud the author actually mentions the method name / variable name ambiguity specifically

Comment: This `Ripper` advice comes directly from `Ruby Under a Microscope`, an excellent book.

Comment: The Ruby grammar, like a lot of programming languages, is highly complicated. There's been efforts to better quantify it, such as the [Ruby Spec Suite](https://github.com/ruby/spec) project, but it can be extraordinarily difficult to explain in simple terms due to nuances. The parser typically explores a number of plausible interpretations, then fits the one that makes the most sense. `a /b/i` depends entirely in `a` being a method or not, and `a=1` reverts that to a variable, changing the meaning. Ruby is pretty forgiving, and often forgiving means dizzyingly complicated grammars.

Comment: This is why writing Ruby compilers is seriously difficult. You cannot even be assured what the result of something trivial like `1+2` will be without knowing *everything* that came before that code, and everything that *might* come after.

Comment: @tadman An interesting addendum. In `jirb` for `Jruby-9.1.5.0` you get ```warning: `/' after local variable or literal is interpreted as binary operator``` upon `a /b/i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby (and some other languages), operators are actually methods of the objects in your expression. Thus Ruby sees your expression as:

```
(a./(b))./(c)
```

When you use regexes there is no leading object so Ruby can figure out that you want a regex and not division.

[Here is a nice article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-operators-and-their-methods--net-18163) for more info.

Comment: Ah! The leading object part was the part that tripped me up. I'm assuming there are no flags before expressions in Ruby.

Comment: I am not sure, I just know that Scala uses this paradigm for operators and it turns out Ruby is the same.

Comment: You are correct. It was the idea of the prefix vs postfix flags that tripped me up.

Comment: @EliSadoff note that I fixed the parens to reflect the actual parse (a / b which is then divided by c)